# Sum of data in a totals report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to do a reasonably simply report but I'm new to this and struggling.

I have two tables, Properties and Incidents.

In the Properties Table I have an ID, the Name of the property (Name) and Number of rooms (NoOfRooms).

In the Incidents table I have the ID, Property that it relates to(PropertyID),DateOpened, DateClosed and Status.

In the report I've managed to get it to show me the number of incidents per property and then the number of incidents closed per bed space.

However, in the summary what I want it to do is total up all of the incidents in that month, which I've done. But then divide that number by the total number of beds.

Where the problem is coming in is it's adding up all of the number of beds multiple times.

So if the data looks like this:

```
Property Name   IncidentID      No of Beds
Property1       1               100
Property1       2               100
Property2       3               200
Property2       4               200
Property2       5               200
```

I Have it showing:

```
Propery Name    No Of Incidents      Incidents / Bed
Property1       2                    0.02
Property2       3                    01015
```

But I can't get it to show the summary which should be:

```
No of Incidents          Incidents / Bed
5                        5/300 = 0.016666667
```

I have the No of incidents that's ok, it's just the final incidents / bed where it recognises there's only 300 beds and not 800.

Comment: Does your report go down to IncidentID level? If not then change your data so that there is only 1 row per property (using group by).

Comment: No, it's just at a property level. How Do I do this?? I have it displaying ok for the individual properties, it's just the overall value that I can't get it to work for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might struggle to do this at the report level.

I would solve this by expanding the underlying Dataset:

```
Property Name   IncidentID      No of Beds  Total Beds
Property1       1               100         300
Property1       2               100         300
Property2       3               200         300
Property2       4               200         300
Property2       5               200         300
```

If you're just extracting this from a database the SQL shouldn't be too difficult and it the subsequent report-level code should also be fairly straightforward.

Ultimately, SSSRS struggles with these sorts of aggregates where you're aggregating at the group level (taking a Distinct *No Of Beds* value) then applying another aggregate at higher level (the Sum of the Distinct *No Of Beds* values).

SSRS 2008 R2 does offer an aggregate of aggregate option, so if you're using 2008 R2 you can use the following expression to do this:

```
=CountRows() / Sum(Max(Fields!NoOfBeds.Value, "PropertyName"))
```

Where *PropertyName* is the name of the Group.

But for 2008 you're best to just add the *Total Beds* to the Dataset level.

Also, user @Tom Jenkin makes a good point; if you're only interested in property level detail you can change your Dataset to already be aggregated, e.g. if it's generated by a SQL statement, use `GROUP BY` to only return two rows for the above data; this would be suitable, too.

**Edit after comment:**

I created a report based on your sample Dataset:

[image]

[image]

You can see there is a Row Group called *PropertyName* that has been created.

The expression for *Total Beds* is `=Sum(Max(Fields!NoOfBeds.Value, "PropertyName"))`.

The expression for *Final Percent* is

`=CountRows() / Sum(Max(Fields!NoOfBeds.Value, "PropertyName"))`

as above.

This is giving the required results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Ian, I'm using SSRS 2008 R2, when I try to do as you've suggsted in the =countRows() solution I get an error. I think it's because I'm using the wrong field in the Group as you say. Where would I get the group name from? Would it be in the tablix or if it a field in my dataset?

Comment: @Pipster1981, I've added more details above showing the report in action. Short answer, the group name is defined as an object in the report. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is very nearly perfect and indeed is perfect apart from me not giving you all of the information... SORRY!! It works perfectly when it's done as a total but I want it broke down per month and I have a Column Group "Month_Opened" when I run the query I get an error  "The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox10' uses both row and column scopes or scopes from two different data axes in the same aggregate expression." what do I need to do???

Comment: @Pipster1981, what would be most helpful right now would be updating the question with half a dozen simplified example rows, enough to illustrate your dataset, and a description of your required output - similar to what I tried to do in the answer if that helps.